# Limit access to route by parameter value

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I have a route like the following :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'    => 'reports'
], function () {
     Route::get('/points/{product_name}', ['uses' => 'MyController@get'])->where('product_name', ['product1', 'product2','product3'])
});
```

So I would like to limit the access to this endpoint id the product name is `product1`, `product2`, `product3`. But with the `where` clause, I can only see checking with regular expression or a single value.

When I use an array like `['product1', 'product2', 'product3']`, but it is throwing an error `"message": "Routing requirement for "product_name" must be a string."`

How can I solve this?

Comment: implode(',', ['product1', 'product2', 'product3']);

Comment: Show the code where you do the where and the array.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I think this logic should be part of the controller and not the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For routes in laravel u can use it like this:

`where('product_name', 'product1|product2|product3'])`

or whith array:

`where('product_name', implode("|", ['product1', 'product2','product3']))`

Answer (score 2):

According to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance. The where method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained. So you should do as follow:

```
$allowedParams = implode('|',['product1','product2','product3']);
// it will return you a string as 'product1|product2|product3'
Route::get('/points/{product_name}', ['uses' => 'MyController@get'])
           ->where('product_name', $allowedParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send with [`implode();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) and to receive using [`explode();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

**Send example:**

```
$array_send = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'];
$imp_send = implode(",", $aray_send);
// return: product1,product2,produtct3
```

**Receive Example:**

```
$array_receive = explode(',', '$product_name');
// return again array
```

Comment: Where to use this ? in `where` clause in the route ?

Comment: @HappyCoder you can pass on the route using the implode, and on time and receive using the explode and get sent array.

Comment: @HappyCoder Now that I understand, the where in the route is only to create a constraint, to pass an array and necessary to be associative: for example `->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+'))`